# C# process lingers after all threads have terminated

Tags: c#, multithreading, termination

I have a multithreaded C# "console" application with lots of threads trhat finishes up.  All my threads exit.  90% of the time the application gracefully exits.  But 10% of the time a copy of my application lingers: console still open.

I attach to this via Visual Studio 2010 and use break to interrupt it, and am shown two "empty" stack frames: one for Main and one for one of my application-created threads.  Neither has anything on the stack.  Visual Studio says that "source code is not available for the thread" if I click on either of these threads, and it offers a "dissambled code view" link.  I click on that and it says "disassembled code is not available for this thread".

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Disable Just My Code in Debugger Options and try again.

Comment: Are you calling Environment.Exit to explicitly terminate your process?

Comment: It quite looks like a problem I already had, but in my case I had no way to even pause debugging!! +Fav. By the way, do you correctly fork and join all threads? Can you inspect the stack trace of pending threads up to your managed code? For example, a thread may be blocked in a semaphore, which is partially unmanaged.

Comment: I'm coding a library, so I don't have control over all the user threads and they don't know about my threads.  But the upshot is that no, I can't call join to collect thread state.  Instead, I'm (trying) to have all my threads terminate by just returning from their initial method, and then my theory was that when the main thread also terminates the process address space would go away.  And usually, it does.  But sometimes seems to hang around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you code shut down after some extra minutes. It could be that some .net helper thead or garbage collection thread is still running. That might take some extra time.

Are you running a debug build or a release build and are you sure the process is not one of those visual studio hosted processes that keeps running for design purposes.

Comment: Good question.  I'll check into that; could explain my problem.

Comment: Barfieldmv, I think you have it right.  Most of my threads were catching the exceptions that shut them down, but one was throwing an uncaught "IsisShutdown" exception.  The thread stack unwound and I guess Windows wasn't sure what to do with the exception and leaves things in this strange state with two "empty" threads.  It didn't report the exception, but it seems that when I catch it the problem doesn't occur.  And it happens 10% of the time because of a race condition, basically.  Thanks!